# Adding a part of the data.table name as a suffix to the column names

Tags: r, function, paste

The following function adds a suffix to each column of the data.table:

```
thefunction <- function (data) {
colnames(data) <- paste(colnames(data), "example", sep = "_")
data
}

library(data.table)  
Session1_TopicA_Part3 <- fread(
    "A   B  C  D  E  F  iso   year   
     0   A   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     1   Y   NA  2  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     0   Q   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     1   NA  NA  4  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     0   0   NA  7  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     1   1   NA  1  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     0   1   NA  3  NA  NA  AUS   2012   
     0   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009   
     1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2009   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  0   BRA   2011   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  0   BRA   2011   
     0   NA  1   NA  7  NA  ECU   2008   
     1   NA  0   NA  1  0   ECU   2008   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2012   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012",
   header = TRUE
)

Session1_TopicA_Part3 <- thefunction(Session1_TopicA_Part3)
```

I would however like the suffix which is to be added, to be ONLY A PART of the data.table name (a total of 64 different data.tables), which would in this example lead to the suffix `_TopicA_Part3`.

How do I adapt the syntax to makes this happen?

EDIT: The desired result is dependent on the data.table name.

If the data.table name is `Session1_TopicA_Part3`, the suffix is `_TopicA_Part3`.

If the data.table name is `Session2_TopicB_Part6`, the suffix is  `_TopicB_Part6`.

If the data.table name is `Session4_TopicA_Part7`, the suffix is  `_TopicA_Part7`.

EDIT 2: I am now trying the following:

```
thefunction <- function (data) {
object_name <- get("data") # To get the string of the object "data" added to the function.
object_name1 <- paste0("_", sapply(strsplit(object_name,"_"), `[`, 3))
object_name2 <- paste0("_", sapply(strsplit(object_name,"_"), `[`, 2))
object_name <- paste0(object_name1,object_name2)
colnames(data) <- paste(colnames(data), object_name, sep = "_")
data
}
```

But somehow this always returns something like "data", instead of `Session1_TopicA_Part3`.

Comment: Simply to clarify, in this example you would like your column to be named : ``A_TopicA_Part3, B_TopicA_Part3, C_TopicA_Part3 ...`` ?

Comment: Get  the dataset's name from your environment, extract the relevant part and paste?

Comment: @Gainz No, not exactly. I want it to be the `_something_something` part of the data.table name that I put into the function.

Comment: @NelsonGon I'm not very familiar with extracting.. I there anyway you could show me how to do it?

Comment: Could you show what the names will turn into with this example?

Comment: you can extract a character string like this :``sapply(strsplit(string,"_"), `[`, 2)``. Output is : ``"Topic1Test". Then you can simply ``paste()``.

Comment: Please show clearly what you want the result to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you ?

```
string <- "sometext_Topic1Test" # This is your object name from the envir.
paste0("_", sapply(strsplit(string,"_"), `[`, 2))
```

Output : `"_Topic1Test"`

You can find your object name this way :

```
object_name <- deparse(quote(object))

this also work :

object_name <- deparse(substitute(data))
```

output is : `"object"`

Then you simply have to add the output to your column names.

Comment: So the only additional thing I would need is to turn the object name which is put into the function into a string..

Comment: Yes you can simply use the object name as a character string.

Comment: Thanks! I'm almost there! But your code only adds `_Tax`, instead of `_Tax_Part3` at the moment.

Comment: I see that this problem develops because of the naming convention. Anyway to prevent this?

Comment: I have fixed it as follows `object_name <- deparse(quote(Session1_TopicA_Part3))
object_name1 <- paste0("_", sapply(strsplit(object_name,"_"), `[`, 3))
object_name2 <- paste0("_", sapply(strsplit(object_name,"_"), `[`, 2))
object_name <- paste0(object_name1,object_name2)`

Comment: @Tom Yes your solution is good! Sorry I didn't think about the second ``_`` when I wrote my answer.

Comment: One more thing.. Could it be that `object_name <- deparse(quote(object))` does not work in a function? I put a print function behind it and it just makes a string of the word instead of the object provided to the function..

Comment: You mean if ``data`` is your argument name and the data.table is ``table1`` then ``deparse(quote(data))`` returns ``"data"`` instead of ``"table1"``?

Comment: ahhh sorry just think of it, try to use ``get(data)``. It should work. So ``deparse(quote(get(data)))``. I'm pretty sure it has to do with scooping but this should do the trick. Tell me if its works for you.

Comment: It is now returning `"get(data)"` hahaha.

Comment: ``deparse(substitute(data))`` seems to works for me. Not sure why it works better in a function than ``deparse(quote(data))``.

Comment: For me they keep working outside the function, but not within the function (it now keeps returning the whole dataframe instead of the quoted name). I have no idea why this could be.. I made an edit to the post to show a more complete overview of the function. Super weird.

Comment: @Tom Simply change the first line of your function to : ``object_name <- deparse(substitute(data))``. It works just fine on my pc and it returns the data with the good column names. Also note that you should switch the 2nd and 3rd line if you want to have the good name order for your columns.

Comment: It works now. Although I am still not entirely sure why..  Nevertheless, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help! Also it's most probably because of scooping.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
the_function = function(tablename){
  # tablename <- deparse(quote(Session1_TopicA_Part3)) # to save your variable name in a string
  table = eval(parse(text = tablename))
  # tablename = substitute(table)
  cat(tablename)
  splitted.name = strsplit(tablename, split = '_')
  to_add = paste(splitted.name[[1]][2], splitted.name[[1]][3], sep = '_')
  colnames(table) = paste(colnames(Session1_TopicA_Part3), to_add, sep = "_")

  return(table)
}

the_function('Session1_TopicA_Part3')
```

And then apply the function on the different table names

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I use it I get an error on this line though: `splitted.name = strsplit(tablename, sep = '_')`. Also: `colnames(Session1_TopicA_Part3)` should be `colnames(table)` I guess right?

Comment: right I edited accordingly. Also note that the function should be called using the variable names (as strings), not the variable itself